# Alert directive not showing after it has been rendered once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive to display an alert message every time a post call succeeds/fails. The alert for the first post always succeeds but if I close the alert, and trigger another post the alerts don't show anymore.

Some code below:

Include tag in html

`<alert message="notification"></alert>`

Directive

```
app.directive("alert", function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: "alert.html",
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
                message: "=",
                close: "&"
            },
            link: function(){

            }
        };
    });
```

Template

```
<div class="alert alert-{{message.type}}" ng-show="message.text">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div>{{message.text}}</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: http://plnkr.co/edit/mECmQNSgW0EdXZGPmkNx?p=preview

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind posting a fiddle so we'd see the exact problem?

Comment: better make a service for the alert, not a directive, because you are showing it dynamically after each post added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `data-dismiss="alert"` you can have your close button call the close function. The close function can then clear the notifications since you have `$scope.notification` in the isolated scope as `scope.message`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.notification = {};

  $scope.alertNotif = function() {
    $scope.notification.type = "error";
    $scope.notification.text = "demo text";
  };
});


app.directive("alert", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div class="alert alert-{{message.type}}" ng-show="message.text">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
      '<div>{{message.text}}</div>' +
      '</div>',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    scope: {
      message: "=",
      close: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.close = function() {
        scope.message = {};
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
    <button ng-click="alertNotif()">test</button>
    <alert message="notification"></alert>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-usage) (emphasis mine):

> … Closing an alert **removes** it from the DOM.

Because it's removed from the DOM it will not show up again...